# Lists - RemoveFirst gets NullPointerException

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a removeFirst() using lists that removes the first node of the list and returns the value removed.

Here's what I've got:

```
    public E removeFirst() {
        E value=first.val;

        first=first.next;
        size--;
        return value;
}
    public void addLast(E v) {
    last = new Node(v,last);
    size++;
}
```

Other classes:

```
class Cliente {
String nome;
int tchegada;
int np;

Cliente(String n, int tc, int p) {
    nome = n;
    tchegada = tc;
    np = p;
} 
}
```

The list:

```
    class List<E>  {
private int size;
private Node first;
private Node last;

public boolean isEmpty() {return (size == 0);}
public int size() {return size;}

// construtor de lista vazia
List() {
    size = 0;
    first = last = null;
}

// um no da lista
private class Node {
E val;
Node next;

Node(E v, Node n) {
    val = v;
    next = n;
}
}
(...)
```

Main:

```
    class Prob106_v0 {

public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// Read the flag
int flag   = in.nextInt();

// Read the boxes to an array
int n        = in.nextInt();
Caixa caixas[] = new Caixa[n];
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    int k = in.nextInt();
    caixas[i] = new Caixa(k);
}

// Read the clients to a list of objects
int c = in.nextInt();
List<Cliente> clientes= new List<Cliente>();
for (int i=0; i<c; i++) {
    String nome       = in.next();
    int tempo_chegada = in.nextInt();
    int num_produtos  = in.nextInt();
    clientes.addLast(new Cliente(nome, tempo_chegada, num_produtos));       
}   

// Flag 0 - Remove each client and write the name of the one just removed
if(flag == 0) {     
    while(!clientes.isEmpty()) {
    Cliente cli = clientes.removeFirst();
    System.out.println(cli.nome);       
    }
} else {     
    // This doesn't matter, it's another part of the program I haven't finished.
    Subtarefas.resolve(flag, n, caixas, clientes);  
}
}
```

}

Resuming, I am supposed to remove the first element of the list 'clientes' and return what I just removed, in this case the client name (cliente.nome), until there is nothing to remove (null).

But I'm getting NullPointException

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at List.removeFirst(Prob106_v0.java:80)
at Prob106_v0.main(Prob106_v0.java:135)
```

EDIT: The RemoveFirst won't be used when the list is empty. But I found out when the size is 1, the exception generates. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your List has only one element this snippet:

```
  public E removeFirst() {
        E value=first.val;

        first=first.next;
        size--;
        }

        return value;
}
```

will result in `NullPointException`

```
 public E removeFirst() {
            E value=first.val;
           if (size>=2)
           {
           first=first.next;                            
           }
           else if (size==1)
           {
            last=null;
           }
            size--;                
            return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure there's something in your list, or else `removeFirst()` will blow up

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `first=first.next;` 
If your list has only one element, there will be no next node, hence null.

Comment: But what should I do to fix it?
Tried adding a condition, still get the same.

Comment: First determine which line that return the exception (in your case line 80 in Prob_106.java). If the error line is first=first.next; then try: if size + 1 -> value = first.val; first = null; If size>1 -> do normally. Sorry for the bad formatting, I'm new to this :P